# My button is getting override by an material ui avatar image onClick

Tags: html, user-interface, material-ui, next.js

Whenever making a simple category filter which should include images, I keep getting a bug. When I console log, it turns out with the button my img is being clicked and being fired as an image, but when clicked around the edges the button is being fired and doing what I want it to do.
I can't have users experiencing this bug, please help.

My code:

```
...
                <Fab
                    key={id}
                    variant="extended"
                    size="medium"
                    color="info"
                    aria-label="add"
                    value={id}
                    onClick={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
                >
                    <Avatar alt={name} src={icon} />
                </Fab>

...
```

Is there a better way to design this ui? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are having issues that the image is capturing the events. I'd suggest you test something on CSS.

1 - Create a class `avatar` in your CSS file.

```
.avatar {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

2 - Add this class to your component.

```
<Avatar className="avatar" ...
```

When you set that CSS pointer-events to none it means the Avatar component won't register it and it will let the events pass through.